# Падает сервер остаётся соединение

Tags: python, сервер, http, flask, httpclient

Привет. Есть flask, который общается с браузером по http. Почему-то иногда, после выполнения Ctrl+C оказывается, что у меня остаётся висеть сосединение, но с ним не связан никакой процесс. Следовательно я не могу переконнектиться заново к браузеру, так как данный порт и адрес заняты. Как убить соединение под Ubuntu 16.04?

Вот что выдаёт netstat:

```
$ netstat -na | grep :8080
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Вот пример кода сервака:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import json
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/search/3', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def GetFromBrowser():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        try:
            connection = requests.get("http://localhost:8082/search/3", params = request.args)
        except:
            print("python: Unexpected connection")
            return ""
# ...
        return connection.text
    else:
        return ""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = '127.0.0.1', port = '8080')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего дело в строках:

```
try:
    connection = requests.get("http://localhost:8082/search/3", params = request.args)
except:
    print("python: Unexpected connection")
    return ""
```

При нажатии `Ctrl+C` во время выполнения `requests.get()` возбуждается ошибка `KeyboardInterrupt`, которая обрабатывается Вашим `except`. Таким образом, скрипт не падает.

Попробуйте проверить работу скрипта командой `ps -ef | grep python`.

Часто в программах можно увидеть такую обработку `KeyboardInterrupt`:

```
import time
try:
    time.sleep(100) # Просто для примера
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Здесь возможно какое-нибудь логирование или сообщение в консоль')
    exit(0)
```

Comment: Лучше отдельно обработать это исключение?

Comment: @hedgehogues дополнил ответ

Answer (score 1):

привет. А ты попробуй найти процесс который остается висеть, может потом поймешь в чем проблема.

1. `lsof -i tcp:8080` ну или `netstat -nap | grep :443`
2. можешь попробовать рабобраться почему соединение не обрубается в логах процесса, а можешь просто прибить процесс - `kill -s KILL <pid который выведет lsof>`